# iphone-Identifying container of a button

Tags: iphone, class, uiview, containers

I have a class like this,

```
@interface event
{
NSString *name;
UIButton *button;
}
```

In my view controller i am having several objects of event class, and i added all the buttons of those event objects to the view controllers class(self.view)

```
-(void) buttonPressed:(id) sender
```

Now i am handling the touchevent in my view controller as given above, now how can i identify the event object to which the pressed button(sender) belongs to.

Comment: Access to an element's the owner breaks the logic of a class structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply compare the button property of the event object to the sender parameter of your action method.  Assuming that your event objects are simply member variables of your view controller, your buttonPressed code might look something like this:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if (sender == event1.button) {
       NSLog(@"Button pressed for event1");
    }
    else if (sender == event2.button) {
       NSLog(@"Button pressed for event2");
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll have to declare button as a @property of your Event object.

Comment: thank you, very much for ur reply!! but what if, if i have many number of buttons created dynamically?? even if have a loop construct to check through the array of event objects (which may be more than 1000) it causes performance degradation...so any other possible solution through the buttons properties itself???

Comment: Wow.  That's a lot of buttons.  You could implement a custom button subclass and give it a `@property (nonatomic, assign) id <Event> eventObject;`.  Then you could call `[((ButtonSubclass *)sender).eventObject someMethod]` in your event handler.  Make sure the eventObject property isn't retained to avoid circular references.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a tag to your objects like:

myObject.tag = 1;

Then, in your buttonPressed method do something like

```
if(sender.tag == 1){
    //...doSomething
}
```

Comment: thank you, very much for ur reply!! but what if, if i have many number of buttons created dynamically????